# Convert PHP associative array to new array but only with specific keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I have data array on this way:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "Register Page"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Login Page"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
  [2]=>
  NULL
}
```

My goal is to get from the array above something like this:

```
array(5,6,null);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the PHP function [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$array = [
   ["name" => "Register Page", "id" => 5 ],
   ["name" => "Login Page", "id" => 6 ],
   NULL
];

$ids = array_map( function($rec) { return $rec['id'] ?? null; }, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in `$a`:

```
foreach ( $a as $a2 ) {
  if ( is_array($a2) && $a2['id'] ) {
    $r[] = $a2['id']; // or (int) $a2['id'] if you want to cast it to an int
  } else {
    $r[] = NULL;
  }
}
```